# jQuery De-Select

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select all the textareas, but not textareas with a certain class associated with them.  How do I de-select an element w/ jQuery?

```
$('textarea' - '.html').autogrow();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [:not](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not) selector, to exclude the textareas containing the class *`html`*:

```
$('textarea:not(.html)').autogrow();
```